# Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]

Tags: installation

I'm getting a installation-error when testing out my app. This is what it says...

```
Device connected: emulator-5554
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554] is online, waiting for processes to start up..
Device is ready: Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554]
Target device: Nexus_5_API_21 [emulator-5554]
Uploading file
    local path: C:\Users\Janne\AndroidStudioProjects\Plugify\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.example.janne.plugify
Installing com.example.janne.plugify
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.example.janne.plugify"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.example.janne.plugify
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]
```

I have no clue what is going on, so your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to include in your build file in `ANDROID_SDK\tools\ant\build.xml` `sigalg` and `digestalg` parameters in the `signjar` section:

```
sigalg="MD5withRSA"
digestalg="SHA1"
```